# Why cant i insert a date sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Trying to insert dates into my SQL Server table, I am using the format `YYYYMMDD`

I'm getting this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 201
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

This is the table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE SupplierOrders
(
    supplierOrderID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    orderDate DATE NOT NULL,
    orderTotal NUMERIC(20,1) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    orderReceiveDate DATE,
    orderPaymentDate DATE ,
    paymentRefNo DATE  ,
    quotationID CHAR(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    PRIMARY KEY (supplierOrderID),
    foreign key (quotationID) 
        references QuotationProduct(quotationID) 
        on update cascade on delete no action
);
```

and this is the data I'm trying to insert

```
INSERT INTO SupplierOrders
VALUES('s9021', '20150101', 10, 'delivered', '20150101', '20150101', 'po900', 'qo1021');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this column in your table.

```
paymentRefNo DATE  ,
```

I think maybe you meant to make it a char or varchar.

You are trying to insert 'po900' into it.

Comment: A yes i just saw that too!, thanks its a late night for me =D